# how to remove [] and "" from column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the row values for one of columns like this ["576373"]   . How can select only 576373

Comment: Guessing here - I am assuming that the value in the column is explicitly either ["576373"] or "576373", with the included quotation marks and possibly the square brackets as well. I'll answer based on this assumption.

Comment: Need more information.   Always 6 digits?   Or varying number?   Are they always numbers?

Comment: Digits can vary  and yeah value is ["932846"]   and i want to get this 932846

Comment: `replace(replace(replace(MyColumn,'[',''),']',''),'"','')`

Comment: Depending on your SQL version, `SELECT JSON_VALUE(YourJsonColumn, '$[0]') FROM dbo.YourTable;`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to get this. A fun way to do it is by using the PARSENAME function.

```
SELECT PARSENAME( PARSENAME( '["576373"]', 1), 1);
```

You could also use nested REPLACE functions. Here's a comparison on both options.

```
SELECT PARSENAME( PARSENAME( SomeString, 1), 1),
       REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( SomeString, '[', ''), ']', ''), '"', '')
FROM (VALUES('["576373"]'), ('[57637]'), ('"76373"'))x(SomeString);
```

Comment: I like the out-of-the-box use of PARSENAME.

Comment: Well done with the parsename !!!   I didn't believe that would work, but it does.  +1

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove the square brackets and quotation marks from a value in a column (as shown in your question above), there are several methods that you can use. Here are a few, based on different situations:

1. The data always includes the [" and "] characters.  In this case, a SUBSTRING will return the data you need most quickly:

In this case, use this code:

```
-- This simply removes those first two and last two characters.
SELECT SUBSTRING(MyColumnName, 3, Len(MyColumnName) - 4) as FinalValue
```

2. The data may include any combination of quotation marks and square brackets - it could be "12345", or [12345], or ["12345"]. For this, a simple `SUBSTRING` is inefficient, since you need to determine the number of characters to remove. In this case, using `REPLACE` would probably be your best bet:

In this case, use this code:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(MyColumnName, '"', ''), ']', ''), '[', '') as FinalValue
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT (replace(replace(replace([fieldName],'[',''),']',''),'"','')) FROM [tableName]`